# Can't Scrape a webpage whose contents are dynamically generated through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape table data from a webpage but it's not a normal webpage that can be scraped using its html tags and CSS class or ID. The contents of the webpage are dynamically generated using JavaScript. This website has multiple pages which can be accessed using 'Next' button. I want the exact table data from all pages to be exported in CSV format. Here is the URL- https://admissions.nic.in/admiss/admissions/orcrjacd/105012321

1. I tried using selenium library and chrome webdriver but nothing seems to work. Here is the code that i tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

def scrape_table(url):
    service = Service('chromedriver.exe')  #chromedriver executable Path
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
    driver.get(url)
    
    # Wait for all tables to be present
    WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'table')))
    
    tables = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'table')
    dfs = []
    for table in tables:
        dfs.append(pd.read_html(table.get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0])
    
    driver.quit()
    return pd.concat(dfs)

def export_to_csv(df, filename):
    df.to_csv(filename, index=False)

def scrape_and_export(url, filename):
    df = scrape_table(url)
    export_to_csv(df, filename)
    print(f"Data exported to {filename}")

# My URL and exported file:
url = 'https://admissions.nic.in/admiss/admissions/orcrjacd/105012321'
filename = 'output.csv'
scrape_and_export(url, filename)
```

When i executed the above code, it automatically opened my URL in chrome browser as expected and then exported 'output.csv' file. But this file was blank even though i have set the wait time to 120 seconds. Only the first cell had 'S.No.' in the output file.

2. I have also tried other methods like inspecting the network in developer tool of chrome browser. This method worked for some website but not for this URL.

I tried all day but couldn't figure out how to do it. I would be really glad if anyone can help me out. Thanks

Comment: Instead of checking / waiting for the `table` tag, have you tried waiting for `td.ng-star-inserted`? For example, [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/e6NZfQ1j) seems to work if you paste it to a browser's console after loading the page, and waiting for the table to be populated.

Comment: For example: `EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td.ng-star-inserted'))`. What happens if you replace your `EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'table'))` with what I provided?